# Entity Framework can't get all the related objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

For some reason I can't get all the related objects from my database. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere, but I can't see it. Can anyone help me out please.

I'm trying to get all the related objects from many-to-many relastionships using:

```
            var result = await ec.Organizations.Include(o => o.Countries)
            .ThenInclude(oc => oc.Country)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Businesses)
            .ThenInclude(cb => cb.Business)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.Families)
            .ThenInclude(bf => bf.Family)
            .ThenInclude(f => f.Offerings)
            .ToListAsync();
```

But, past the last ThenInclude I can't go further. It treats a property after lambda as Offerings Collection.
Ideally it should go further and look like this:

```
            var result = await ec.Organizations.Include(o => o.Countries)
            .ThenInclude(oc => oc.Country)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Businesses)
            .ThenInclude(cb => cb.Business)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.Families)
            .ThenInclude(bf => bf.Family)
            .ThenInclude(f => f.Offerings)
            .ThenInclude(fo => fo.Offering)
            .ThenInclude(o => o.Departments)
            .ThenInclude(od => od.Department)
            .ToListAsync();
```

This is my OnModelCreating method in the Context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationCountry>()
           .HasKey(t => new { t.CountryId, t.OrganizationId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationCountry>()
            .HasOne(oc => oc.Organization)
            .WithMany(o => o.Countries)
            .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.OrganizationId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationCountry>()
            .HasOne(oc => oc.Country)
            .WithMany(c => c.Organizations)
            .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.CountryId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CountryBusiness>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.BusinessId, t.CountryId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CountryBusiness>()
            .HasOne(cb => cb.Country)
            .WithMany(c => c.Businesses)
            .HasForeignKey(cb => cb.CountryId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CountryBusiness>()
            .HasOne(cb => cb.Business)
            .WithMany(b => b.Countries)
            .HasForeignKey(cb => cb.BusinessId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BusinessFamily>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.FamilyId, t.BusinessId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<BusinessFamily>()
            .HasOne(bf => bf.Business)
            .WithMany(b => b.Families)
            .HasForeignKey(bf => bf.BusinessId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BusinessFamily>()
            .HasOne(bf => bf.Family)
            .WithMany(f => f.Businesses)
            .HasForeignKey(bf => bf.FamilyId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<FamilyOffering>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.OfferingId, t.FamilyId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<FamilyOffering>()
            .HasOne(fo => fo.Family)
            .WithMany(f => f.Offerings)
            .HasForeignKey(fo => fo.FamilyId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<FamilyOffering>()
            .HasOne(fo => fo.Offering)
            .WithMany(o => o.Families)
            .HasForeignKey(fo => fo.OfferingId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OfferingDepartment>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.DepartmentId, t.OfferingId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<OfferingDepartment>()
            .HasOne(od => od.Offering)
            .WithMany(o => o.Departments)
            .HasForeignKey(od => od.OfferingId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OfferingDepartment>()
            .HasOne(od => od.Department)
            .WithMany(d => d.Offerings)
            .HasForeignKey(od => od.DepartmentId);
    }
```

This is my Family and Offering Entities with navigation properties class. All Entities have many-to-many relationship.

```
 public class Family
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BusinessFamily> Businesses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FamilyOffering> Offerings { get; set; }

        public Family()
        {
            Offerings = new List<FamilyOffering>();
            Businesses = new List<BusinessFamily>();
        }
    }

public class Offering
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FamilyOffering> Families { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OfferingDepartment> Departments { get; set; }

        public Offering()
        {
            Departments = new List<OfferingDepartment>();
            Families = new List<FamilyOffering>();
        }
    }

public class FamilyOffering
    {
        public int FamilyId { get; set; }
        public Family Family { get; set; }

        public int OfferingId { get; set; }
        public Offering Offering { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is some Visual Studio IntelliSense bug. IntelliSense doesn't show the properties of type FamilyOffering, but it shows properties of List instead.

[image: IntelliSense don't show property]

But the properties of type FamilyOffering is there. No error is shown

[image: But it's there]